# How to make Omniauth work with a popup window?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, oauth, twitter-oauth, omniauth

The default for Omniauth works beautifully if you are opening it in the existing window, but not sure how it works in a popup context, and you are handling a large part of the interactions via javascript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like you could do this yourself?

When user clicks 'login via facebook' - use JS to pop open a window with a location of /auth/facebook. The 'callback' will just route back to /auth/callback in this same window. Once you've done your work with the callback, close the current window and refresh the parent?

Comment: thanks cory! is /auth/callback a generic function that handles the various networks?

Answer (score 16):

```
var newwindow;
function login(provider_url, width, height) {
  var screenX     = typeof window.screenX != 'undefined' ? window.screenX : window.screenLeft,
      screenY     = typeof window.screenY != 'undefined' ? window.screenY : window.screenTop,
      outerWidth  = typeof window.outerWidth != 'undefined' ? window.outerWidth : document.body.clientWidth,
      outerHeight = typeof window.outerHeight != 'undefined' ? window.outerHeight : (document.body.clientHeight - 22),
      left        = parseInt(screenX + ((outerWidth - width) / 2), 10),
      top         = parseInt(screenY + ((outerHeight - height) / 2.5), 10),
      features    = ('width=' + width + ',height=' + height + ',left=' + left + ',top=' + top);

      newwindow = window.open(provider_url, 'Login', features);

  if (window.focus)
    newwindow.focus();

  return false;
}
```

Replace provider_url with '/auth/facebook' or '/auth/twitter' should work.

At your callback url,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.opener.location = '<%= @redirect_to %>';
  window.close();
</script>
```

You can refresh the page however you want with @redirect_to pointing to the page where your parent window should be refreshed to.

Comment: that was almost exactly how i did that in the end. Thanks! =D

Comment: altho i triggered the js call from the controller

render :text => "<script>window.opener.oauth_success(#{user.to_json}); </script>", :type => 'html'

Comment: it will be faster if you render with :layout => false

Comment: by doing #{user.to_json} is a really bad idea. you actually returning your user's access token back to him. if your authentication is done under unsecured network, other people will be able to access the access token.

Comment: Is there a list of recommended widths/heights for different providers somewhere?

Comment: In most cases for opener: window.opener.location.reload();